# WHERE clause with IN (DB LINK) and local contraints: slow query

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

I don’t understand why this query is very slow (+5 min):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
OR (a.ID) IN ( SELECT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r);


----------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name          | Cost  |
----------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |               |  1586 |
|   1 |  FILTER            |               |       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOCAL         |  1586 |
|   3 |   REMOTE           | REMOTE        |     2 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

There is no index on `CREATIE_DT`.

In all the following cases the query executes very fast (~10ms):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

----------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name           | Cost  |
----------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                |  1576 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| LOCAL          |  1576 |
----------------------------------------------------

SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE (a.ID) IN ( SELECT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r);

--------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name               | Cost  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |     5 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |         |     5 |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE                |         |     2 |
|   3 |    REMOTE                    | REMOTE  |     2 |
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LOCAL   |     2 |
|   5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PRKE_PK |     1 |
----------------------------------------------- --------

SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE  a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
OR (a.ID) = ( SELECT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r);
```

Note the **`=`** in the last case (!).
Anyone any idea’s?

I have tried `/*+ DRIVING_SITE(a) */` hint, but it has no effect.

**If someone knows a hint I can use in this case, to force the execution engine to cache the results of the remote query, please advise, and I will accept your answer.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have answered it yourself.

The version with `in` causes the Oracle optimizer to re-run the subquery multiple times for each row.  The version with the `=` is optimized, so Oracle just makes on call to the remote server and caches the result.

You can probably fix this by doing the query as a `join`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM local a JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r
      ) r
     ON a.ID = r.ID
WHERE a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Note the use of `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` to prevent row duplication.  This may not be necessary if you know that `r.id` is unique.

EDIT:

To get the equivalent of the original query (where there is an `or` instead of `and`):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM local a LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r
      ) r
     ON a.ID = r.ID
WHERE a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') or
      r.ID is not null;
```

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't the exec-engine not use the index in the first case?

Comment: @davor . . . The subject of optimizing remote accesses is rather long.  The place to start is with the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_appdev004.htm#ADMIN12196.  But, the short answer is that because the data is not co-located on the same server, the engine has to bring the data over.  This reduces the options available for optimizing the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, thanks. As you noted, I assumed that the remote query would be cached. Also, your solution is fast, but isn't equivalent with the query in the question. The question uses an OR-relationship.

Comment: @davor . . . I added the equivalent query for the `or`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, how does this perform?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE a.CREATIE_DT > to_date('17/06/2014 10:30:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
UNION
SELECT a.*
FROM local a
WHERE (a.ID) IN ( SELECT r.ID FROM remote@testsite r);
```

It's probably a good idea to have an index on CREATIE_DT

Comment: Fast!! But I prefer the above Gordon Linoff's solution which uses indexes. Thank you anyway!